# How to disable emojis from android keyboard in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms. I am creating app for android. I need to disable the emojis from android keyboard from c#. How I can do this in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to remove the Emoji in the Keyboard. `<Entry Keyboard="Email" />`

[image: Keyboard with our Emoji]

Or Please use this Custom Renderer to achieve this.

**Create Custom Renderer for Entry**

Create a class in Shared or PCL Project.

```
public class MyEntry:Entry
{
}
```

Use this Custom Code in XAML like below code

```html
<custom:MyEntry x:Name="myEntry" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

Create a Class for Custom renderer in Android Project

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {        
        public MyEntryRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);            
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done;
                    Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword| Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagMultiLine;
                    Control.SetTypeface(Typeface.Default, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround. The XF team should probably address it directly but this is definitely the easiest way in the meantime.

Comment: I have updated this answer using custom renderer. Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

**Create Custom Renderer for Entry**

Create a class in Shared or PCL Project.

```
public class MyEntry:Entry
{
}
```

Use this Custom Code in XAML like below code

```html
<custom:MyEntry x:Name="myEntry" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

Create a Class for Custom renderer in Android Project

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {        
        public MyEntryRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);            
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done;
                    Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword| Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagMultiLine;
                    Control.SetTypeface(Typeface.Default, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Keyboard type to text in Entry.

```
<Entry Keyboard="Text" />
```

Emoji's will be shown when the Keyboard type is

```
<Entry Keyboard="Chat" />
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/

Comment: I tried this but its not working. I am still getting Emoji on keyboard.